# move_uploaded_file php no images uploaded

Tags: php

I have a problem with the move_uploaded_file function. The problem is when I choose the image I want to upload, it doesn't upload into the product_images.
Please help me sort out my block of code.

Here is my html code:

```
<form> action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php

if(isset ($_POST['insert_post'])) {


    // Getting the text data from the fields
    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

    // Getting the image from the field

    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

    $root = "product_images";


    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,$root.$product_image);

    $insert_product = "insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) "
        . "values ('$product_cat','$product_brand',' $product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";


    $insert_pro = mysqli_query($link, $insert_product);

    if($insert_pro){

        echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";

    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked if the size of the image might be to big (-> try a small one)?

Comment: check: `ini_get('post_max_size')`, `ini_get('memory_limit')`, `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`.

Comment: and I assume the html-code is not the actual copy&paste one, right? cause there's a `>` too much/early after `<form`

Comment: Ok so the main problem that I am currently having is that when I hit the upload button, it doesn't go directly into the folder 'product_images'. It directly goes to my main www directory. Any tips?

Comment: Oh don't worry about the html, I just copied that one line.

Comment: yes, add a `/` or a `\\`` to `$root` - depending the OS you're running

Comment: Nope, it still goes directly into the www main directory folder.

Comment: what does the filename look like there? like the original or does it include 'product_images'?

Comment: it contains product_imagesThen the image name. :(

Comment: then the missing `/` might be the problem!

Comment: try: ` move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,$root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$product_image);` (and leave $root without any `/` or `\\`)

Comment: Tried that and it gave me the dreaded No such file or directory in error.

Comment: so the directory product_images does not exist? create it!

Comment: Sorry but can you help me with the creation of the directory of product_image? I'm still kind of weak with php.

Comment: Nevermind I have added it and I think it is working now. I added this code in: 
        $directory_name = 'product_images';

               if(!is_dir($directory_name)){
            mkdir($directory_name, 0755);
        }

Comment: `if(!is_dir($root)) {   mkdir($root, 0755, true); }`

Comment: I'll write a short answer for that....

Comment: However, it only let me upload just ONE image. Whenever I try to upload another one after the first one image that I have uploaded, it doesn't upload any. :(

Comment: Whoops nevermind, it is working. It was just waiting for me to hit the OK  button.

Comment: haha... glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems that I can see:

first you're missing a directory separator (/ or \) here

```
move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp, $root.$product_image);
```

so change that to

```
move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp, $root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$product_image);
// the php constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is practical 
// if you're unaware on what system/os that script might be running
```

second, that directory might not yet exist, so check for that and create it, if not existing (before the move):

```
if(!is_dir($root)) { 
    mkdir($root, 0755, true); // third parameter isn't important in your case though)
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP! REALLY REALLY APPRECIATE IT!